# Evaluating a String which is stored in a variable and assigning to an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, arduino, initialization

Consider this case

```
char x[] = "abcdef";
```

this does not throw any errors.

Now consider second case,

```
String string = "abcdef";
char x[] = string;
```

the second condition throws an error "array must be initialized with a braced-enclosed initializer".
I dont understand this error. Why can't I assign a string variable to an array.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: @Konamiman,The code is for Arduino Sketch which is written in C/C++,we can use C/C++ function in Arduino sketch.The String function is used in Arduino IDE.Sorry for not making it clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

Since its Ardruino I guess it's using a c compiler.
Guessing you use C89, In C89 the size of an array needs to be constant at compile time, so what you are trying is just not supported.

When using your string to define the array the compiler notices it as a variable, not a constant.

```
String string = "abcdef";
char x[] = string; // string = variable, even if it doesn't change.
```

Variable length arrays are supported in C99, so you could compile it with the C99 compiler instead to prevent the error.

Comment: Thanks for the compiler suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

In plain C strings are not entities on its own, they are just arrays of `char` with a `null` at the end. So your first line is just syntactic sugar equivalent to:

```
char x[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','\0'};
```

`String` on the other hand seems to be a C++ class available in your environment, which happens to be initializable with a literal string as well. Instances of this class can **not** be assigned directly to a char array, hence the error (perhaps there is a conversion function somewhere?)

Comment: Yes i came to the same conclusion after banging my head for couple of hours.So what i did was to change the string literal to char array using a predefined function called toCharArray().